# A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow - when redirect to new page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm beginner in the e2e testing and have a problem.
When I do login - I make redirect from login.php to index.php page.
But my test is fails with following errors:

```
..A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
F

Failures:
1) Login Page should login and redirect to overview page with CR Operators rights.
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

3 specs, 1 failure
```

My code:

```
it('should login and redirect to overview page with CR Operators rights', function(sync) {
    element(by.model('username')).clear().sendKeys('testuser');
    element(by.model('password')).clear().sendKeys('test');
    element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/overview');
});
```

So the question is how i can wait when my page will reload and check url?

**UPD**

I make an Ajax POST request and if login/pass are correct I do redirect to /index.php

**UPD 2**

I have tried several constructions with browser.wait (browser.driver.wait) but without any success:

```
it('should login and redirect to overview page with CR Operators rights', function(done) {
    element(by.model('username')).clear().sendKeys('testuser');
    element(by.model('password')).clear().sendKeys('test');
    element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();

    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(element(by.css('body')).getText()).toContain('Welcome Test User');
        done();
    }, 1000);
});
```

and

```
it('should login and redirect to overview page with CR Operators rights', function(done) {
    element(by.model('username')).clear().sendKeys('testuser');
    element(by.model('password')).clear().sendKeys('test');
    element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();

    browser.driver.wait(function() {
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                console.log(url);
                return (/overview/).test(url);
            });
        }, 5000);
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/overview');
    done();
});
```

everything of these don't work :( **BUT** when I don't use *browser* or *element* - it works. E.g.:

```
it('should login and redirect to overview page with CR Operators rights', function(done) {
    element(by.model('username')).clear().sendKeys('testuser');
    element(by.model('password')).clear().sendKeys('test');
    element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();

    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        done();
    }, 1000);
});
```

So I guess that here is a problem when use *browser* and *element* after redirect.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I have resolved this issue by myself, but not sure why *element* and *browser* don't work.
I have changed

```
expect(element(by.css('body')).getText()).toContain('Welcome Test User');
```

to

```
expect(browser.driver.findElement(by.css('body')).getText()).toContain('Welcome Test User');
```

So I have changed *element* to *browser.driver.findElement* and everything works.

I don't know why it happens, but it works :)

**UPD**

As I understand, *browser.driver.findElement* - is not angular way and we should use it if we use non-angular pages. Although I use angular it seems that *element* and *browser* doesn't re-initialize. Some info I found here 
http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/angularapp-e2e-testing-with-protractor/#test-both-angularjs-and-non-angularjs-based-pages

Comment: I invested my whole day in trying to get simple login work and couldn't. It's just that I am able to get it to work only after seeing your post. Thanks a ton mate.

Answer (score 7):

Jasmine has timeout for each spec i.e. each `it` in jasmine framework. so if any spec (`it`) exceeds jasmine spec's default timeout then it fails that spec.

**Solution**:
To override jasmine spec timeout for one individual spec, pass a third parameter to it: 
`it(description, testFn, timeout_in_millis)`

```
it('description of test case', function() {
   /*your test 
               steps
                    here*/
},120000);//120 seconds timeout for this spec
```

more information on  [timeouts is here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md)

Answer (score 4):

You are getting timeout because you've injected a param into `it` callback and never called that (read more on that [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)). You should remove the param, or call it when the test is over. Basically, you don't do any custom async stuff, so you don't need it.

> So the question is how I can wait when my page will reload and check url?

I'd suggest that you waited for a specific element on `index.php` page:

```
it('should login and redirect to overview page with CR Operators rights', function() {
    element(by.model('username')).clear().sendKeys('testuser');
    element(by.model('password')).clear().sendKeys('test');
    element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();
    browser.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(by.css('Log out'));
    expect(element(by.css('body')).getText()).toContain('Hello, you are Logged In!');
});
```

Comment: Hi @Dziamid, I have updated questions. Please, look. Maybe you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
 jasmineNodeOpts: { defaultTimeoutInterval: 260000 }
```

for me this works after including this in conf.js

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(element(by.cssContainingText('body', 'Hello, you are Logged In!')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();

expect(element.all(by.cssContainingText('body', 'Hello, you are Logged In!')).get(2).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

- If you have more than one time the same text in body in array then

Comment: Proper formatting would increase the readability of your suggestions.